# Variable Exchange $F(t) \to F(x)$? I want the value of the work done by drag

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, work, drag

I got a nonlinear equation, which describes the magnitude of a force as a function of time, but I don't know how to calculate the work done by the force. Given:
$$F(t) = kv(t)$$
with
$$v(t)= \left(1-\frac{k}{m}\right)^t v_{0}$$
and I want to derive:
$$W = \int F(t) dx$$
and also want to convert $F(t)$ to $F(x)$

Comment: Welcome to this community! Recall that the work can be written (and is even more appropriately defined) as $$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \pmb{F}(t) \cdot \pmb{v}(t) \ \mathrm{d}t\ .$$

Comment: same $dx\rightarrow \dfrac{dx}{dt}dt$

Comment: Oh, yes. Indeed! Thanks. 
So, how about F(x). Can I transform F(t) to F(x)?

Comment: No, $F$ won't be a function of $x$, but a derivative of it, since the $F$ given depends on $v$. However you don't need that to compute the work. If you are actually interested in $x(t)$ you will have to solve a diff.eq

Comment: @ohneVal  I disagree with your statement for F not being a function of x. F will become a function of x if you can write v as a function of x

Comment: Which holds only if the relation is monotonic, the inverse might not be well defined if the trajectory has the same speed at different positions. All I am saying is, you don't need that to compute the work, which seems the goal here. I believe the OP is unaware of the possibility of changing variables in the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \begin{align}F(t)&=\space kv(t) \\
v&= \frac{dx}{dt}=(1-\large{\tfrac{k}{m}})^{\small{t}}\, v_0\\
{\rm d}x&=(1-{\tfrac{k}{m}})^{\small{t}} v_0 {\rm d}t\\
\int_0^x {\rm d}x&= \int_0^t (1-{\tfrac{k}{m}})^{\small{t}}\, v_0 {\rm d}t\\
x&=\frac{(1-{\frac{k}{m}})^{\small{t}}-1}{\ln(1-{\frac{k}{m}})} v_0\\
(1-{\tfrac{k}{m}})^{\small{t}} v_0&= v(t)= v_0 + x \space \ln(1-{\tfrac{k}{m}})\\ \end{align}$$
Substituting the values in the expression for $F(t)$ $$ \begin{aligned} 
F(x)=k \left[v_0 + x \space \ln(1-{\tfrac{k}{m}})\right]
\end{aligned}$$

I hope you can calculate forward.
Regards.

Comment: A big thank you! I appreciate you! The last calculation is beautiful...

Comment: @SteelCubes $~x={\frac { \left( 1-{\it kk} \right) ^{t}{\it v0}}{\ln  \left( 1-{\it kk
} \right) }}
~$ where $kk=\frac km~$ from hear you can obtain $~t=t(x)$ and substitute this in $~F=k\,v(t)\mapsto \,k\,v(t(x)) $ you obtain $F(x)$

Comment: @Eli Firstly, it is $x= \frac{(1-\frac{k}{m})^t -1}{ln(1-\frac{k}{m})}v_0$. I think you forgot to put the lower limit of t=0 where x=0. And secondly, that's exactly what I did. I mean, I just took a few step forwards to reduce the calculation part. But I did exactly what you're saying.